# Обучение ребенка программированию

Tags: алгоритм

Хочу начать обучение ребенка программированию. Ребенку 7 лет, с основами программирования совсем не знаком. Постоянно играет в Майнкрафт.  Каким образом вызвать у него интерес к программированию? Какие ресурсы можно использовать? Можно ли связать его интерес к игре Майнкрафт с программированием?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне нравятся такие:

1. [www.codingame.com](https://www.codingame.com/)
2. [scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/)
3. [blockly](http://blockly.ru/)

Но это если ребёнок маленький, если ему лет 12 и больше, возможно, стоит посмотреть в сторону более профессиональных ресурсов. По вашему описанию у меня сложилось впечатление, что уровень у ребёнка совсем начинающий, так что, думаю, три ресурса по ссылкам (особенно 2 и 3) подойдут лучше всего. По ссылке 1 это уже посложнее, он подошёл бы детям 12-15 лет...

Comment: https://javarush.ru